# Function calling -Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C. I am porting C++ code into Objective-C. I have
this function call `eventLog()` in
`samples.cpp` and I have declared this
function in `samples.h`. I have its
definition on `EventLog.cpp` by
including the `samples.h` header file.

**samples.h**

```
class samples
{
 declaration;
}
```

**samples.cpp**

```
#include "samples.h"
void samples::buttonClick()
{
 eventLog();
}
```

**EventLog.h**

```
#include "samples.h"
```

**EventLog.cpp**

```
void samples::eventLog()
{
 //definition;
}
```

---

Is this the Objective-C equivalent?

**samples.h**

```
- (void)eventLog;
```

**samples.m**

```
samples* a = [[samples alloc]init];
[a eventLog];
```

**EventLog.h**

```
#import "samples.h"
```

**EventLog.m**

```
-(void)eventLog
{
 //Definition;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good except are you doing your

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EventLog : NSObject {

}
- (void)eventLog;
@end
```

and

```
#import "EventLog.h" 
#import "Samples.h"

@implementation EventLog

- (void)eventLog
{
     //definition
}

@end
```

? If you don't have the class "wrappers" in place, you're bound to run into issues. Also, your files are pretty screwy. If `samples.h` implements `eventLog`, you shouldn't be implementing it in `EventLog.m`. That would be `samples.m`'s job. Refer to my above example for a possible structure.

Comment: I'm not declaring the function eventLog() on EventLog.h file.I'm adding the header where this eventLog() function is declared.I compiled and didnt get any error.But i'm not sure of this declaration as if called [a eventLog] it will search for the function definition in sample.m and not in EventLog.m isnt it.

Comment: But you send a message to an *object*, not to the file that "defines" it.

Answer (score 0):

NO it is wrong...
Create an instance of EventLog.m in sample.m, by using the line:

```
EventLog *obj = [[EventLog alloc] init]; 

Then, use [EventLog eventLog];
```